# SQL Query - add new column if two existing columns match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I want to add a column to an existing table, that returns 'non-match' for the two queries:

```
select * from dbo.customer  
where cus_title IN ('MRS','DAME','SISTER','MISS','MADAME','LADY','MS')  
and cus_gender <> 'F'

select * from pv_customer 
where  cus_title IN ('FATHER','SIR','MR') 
and cus_gender <> 'M'
```

or 'match' if the not selected from the two queries above?

Is someone able to assist with the alter table query?

Many thanks

Comment: Are these really two different tables? And which table do you want to alter?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the column and run an update statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
ADD COLUMN match_status VARCHAR(10) NULL;

UPDATE <table_name> SET match_status = 'match';
```

Assuming this table you are updating has a foreign key to the customer Id, you would then update the non-matched with something like this:

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET match_status = 'non-match' 
WHERE customerId IN (select customerId from dbo.customer where cus_title IN ('MRS','DAME','SISTER','MISS','MADAME','LADY','MS') and cus_gender <> 'F')
OR customerId IN (select customerId from pv_customer where cus_title IN ('FATHER','SIR','MR') and cus_gender <> 'M');
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a computed column! Unlike running an `UPDATE`, a computed column has the advantage of automatically updating if new rows are added or existing rows are updated.

Create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GenderMatch](@title VARCHAR(50), @gender CHAR(1)) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
BEGIN
    IF (((@title IN ('MRS', 'MS', 'MISS')) AND (@gender = 'M'))
        OR
        ((@title IN ('MR', 'SIR', 'FATHER')) AND (@gender = 'F')))
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'non-match'
    END
    RETURN 'match'
END
GO
```

The `WITH SCHEMABINDING` is important if you want to index on this column! Although, if you want to index, I recommend changing the function to return a `BIT`. Heck, using a `BIT` is better for storage, too, and cleaner for other comparisons.

Then alter your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[customer] ADD [MisMatch] AS [dbo].[fn_GenderMatch]([cus_title],[cus_gender])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE [SomeTable] ADD COLUMN Check VARCHAR(10)

UPDATE [SomeTable]
SET Check = 'No Match'

UPDATE S
SET Check = 'Match'
FROM 
[SomeTable] S JOIN dbo.Customers C ON s.CustomerID = C.CustomerId
AND C.cus_title IN
('MRS','DAME','SISTER','MISS','MADAME','LADY','MS')  and C.cus_gender <>
 'F'
JOIN Pv_Customer P ON S.CustomerID = P.CustomerID AND 
P.cus_title IN ('FATHER','SIR','MR')
and P.cus_gender <> 'M'
```